# React + Redux, nothing returned from render()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, jsx

Nothing returned from `render()`, `data` is an `array` and it's not `undefined` or `null` (checked with `debugger`). It iterate all needed data but then nothing returned.

Here you can find full code if it needed: https://github.com/BakuganXD/taskManager/tree/boardUpdate

Component.js:

```
class ProfilePage extends React.Component {

//several functions

render() {
const { loading, error, data, isEditing, editToogle } = this.props;
if (!loading && !error) {
  {data.map( (value, index) => {
    if (!isEditing[value.id]) {
      return (
        //a lot of JSX code, value is not undefined
    } else {
      return (
        //another big JSX part
          );
        }
      }
  ) }
  } else return <p>Loading</p>;
 }
}
```

Comment: Would you mind formatting your code a bit better? What you have here is not syntactically valid.

Comment: It should be `return data.map...` instead of `data.map...`. You don't return anything from `render`, your `return` statements are in `map` itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to return `data.map` results. Also, remove `{}` around `data.map`

```
class ProfilePage extends React.Component {

    //several functions

    render() {
        const { loading, error, data, isEditing, editToogle } = this.props;
        if (!loading && !error) {
            return data.map( (value, index) => {
                if (!isEditing[value.id]) {
                  return (
                    //a lot of JSX code, value is not undefined
                  )
                } else {
                return (
                  //another big JSX part
              );
            }
          })
        } else return <p>Loading</p>;
    }
}
```